# Получить текст из блока span Jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Можно ли сделать как-то так:

```
$('#Header_bottom_big h1 span, #Header_bottom_min h1 span').text();
```

Если первого контейнера нет, получить из второго

Comment: К чему море селекторов? Задайте ссылке класс, скажем .my__link и получайте: $('.my__link').eq(0).text();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('#Header_bottom_big h1 span').length) {
    alert($('#Header_bottom_big h1 span').text());
} else if ($('#Header_bottom_min h1 span').length) {
    alert($('#Header_bottom_min h1 span').text());
}
```